# Function within setTimout has not been called in Unit Test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, settimeout

I trying to test an angular 10 function that call another function within a setTimeout. I am using Karma and Jasmine but I can get to pass the test. I read a lot of examples on blog post, angular documentation and even here in stackoverflow and all points me to this solution:

**MY METHOD**

```
  loadDefault() {
    ... do something
    setTimeout(this.run, 100);    
  }
```

**MY UNIT TEST**

```
  describe('loadDefault', () => {
    it('should call run function after ...', fakeAsync(() => {
      
      const spyRun = spyOn(component, 'run').and.callFake(fakeFn);
      component.loadDefault()   
      tick(101);  
      fixture.detectChanges()
      expect(spyRun).toHaveBeenCalled()

    }))
  });
```

When karma runs shows me those resuls:

[image]

Can you help me identifying whats going wrong?

Comment: I guess you should wrap your setTimout with promise and wait for it in fakeAsync. Because logically what's inside your timeout function will run after your test because of synchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

Try This. I only added the tick function to your code. You can get the tick function from angular core testing modules

```
 describe('loadDefault', () => {
    it('should call run function after ...', fakeAsync(() => {
      
      const spyRun = spyOn(component, 'run').and.callFake(fakeFn);
      component.loadDefault() 
      tick(500)    
      fixture.detectChanges()
      expect(spyRun).toHaveBeenCalled()

    }))
  });
```

Don't forget to import tick from  "@angular/core/testing".

Your import should look something like this

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
```

Comment: I tried to adding tick()  before and did not work. Even If I force onInit with a detectChanges() previous to call tick.